# IF/Else statements on attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I am working on a project that, depending on how you compile the project, you have a secured and unsecured version of the project. In short words,  I would like to know how to deactivate the **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** depending on which version I am running.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ProductInfo(ProductInfoModel review)
    {
       ...

    }
```

Comment: `#if` lets you exclude arbitrary code based on compile settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a compilation symbol (maybe call it SECURED) then check in-line for that symbol:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
#if SECURED
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
#endif
    public ActionResult ProductInfo(ProductInfoModel review)
    {
      ...
    }
```

If you don't like adding it to your project's properties, you can also define it from an MSBuild command:

```
MSBuild [...] /p:DefineConstants=SECURED
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have separate builds for each?  If so, you could add a symbol (Project Properties -> Build) to the build where you don't want it to run and add a #IF inside of the attribute, around the code you don't want to run.

```
#if !DISABLEFORGERY
    ...
#endif
```

You could put it around the attribute definition on the consuming class but you'd have to repeat it in multiple places (potentially).